# Using Spring Security with Spring Starter Web and WebClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring Boot 3 and configured spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux. I added *`Webflux`* to use the *`WebClient`* with `HttpExchange`. I have also created another spring boot project with some rest endpoints to use the WebClient. Second service creates entry in DB.

I have also configured Spring Security in first service and doing JWT based authentication and also configured `@RestControllerAdvice` for error responses in the gateway service.

> Updated question with more details to have more clarity based on
> comments

***The application flow**: So my first service acts as a gateway which does authentication and authorization by directly communicating with DB for user releated tables (This would get changed as the application grows - Could be SSO OAuth2 auth). And the gatwat service also communicates with second service which connects to DB and provide other services like adding customer.*

***Error Flow**: The API to create a  cusomter reached the gateway service controller (it has passed authentication and authorization). The call reached the second service and service respnded succesfully with 201. But the gateway service then responds with 401 instead of the same
201.*

Below is my WebSecurity Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler,
            AppAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler, UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll().requestMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs", "/api-docs/**", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources",
                        "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-ui.html", "/actuator/**")
                .permitAll().requestMatchers("/user/{id}/**").access(new AppAuthorizationManager()).anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider(userDetailsService));
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.error("Authentication error: {}", authException);
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
        var body = AccessResponseUtls.getResponseBody(request, httpStatus);
        objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
    }

}
```

**AccessDeniedHandler**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AppAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException 
  {         
            log.error("Forbidden error: {}", accessDeniedException);
            HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            response.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
            var body = AccessResponseUtls.getResponseBody(request, httpStatus);
            objectMapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
        }
    }
```

I have configured Client via [@HttpExchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0-RC3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/service/annotation/HttpExchange.html) and using WebClient in the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class AppConfig {

    WebClient webClient(String url) {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url)
                //.filter(errorHandler())
                .build();
    }
    
    public static ExchangeFilterFunction errorHandler() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
      log.info("Client Response => {}", clientResponse.bodyToMono(Customer.class));
            log.info("Status Code = {}", clientResponse.statusCode());
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                log.error("Got 5xx Error");
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorBody)));
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                log.error("Got 4xx Error");
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new InvalidParametersException(errorBody)));
            } else {
                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
            }
        });
    }

    @Bean
    CustomerClient customerClient() {
        HttpServiceProxyFactory httpServiceProxyFactory = HttpServiceProxyFactory
                .builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient("http://localhost:8081/api/v1/"))).build();
        return httpServiceProxyFactory.createClient(CustomerClient.class);

    }
}
```

**CustomerClient - Client Interface**

```
    @HttpExchange("/customer")
    public interface CustomerClient {
        @PostExchange
        Mono<ResponseEntity<Customer>> create(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customerDTO);
    }
```

I wrote a test controller which returns some strings to test authentication in the gateway service. Signup, login, testing which are in gateway service works properly. If jwt token is not passed or an invalid token is passed for test controller APIs, the AuthenticationEntryPoint is getting executed returns with 401 and extra custom fields in response. And for some method I have added *hasRole* and for that AccessDeniedHandler is getting executed if the user doesn't have that role and it returns with 403 with custom fields in response. These apis work as expected.

In my gateway service, I have added a controller, for adding customer. Inside that I'm calling the second service using the Client interface (HttpExchange) which is configured to use WebClient.

**Controller Class**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
@Slf4j
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerClient customerClient;

    @PostMapping
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Customer>> create(@RequestBody @Valid CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        log.info("Creating....");
        return customerClient.create(customerDTO);
    }
}
```

The second service is not having any security configured at the moment. It's plain rest service. When I test the service alone through postman, it is working and returns with 201.

Now through gatway service, I tried to call the same API. The authentication and authorization has passed and the call has reached in CustomerController in gatway service. It can be verfied using the logs. And the from there, the call has reached second service as well (verified through logs).

I tried to enable error handler in WebClient (Commented code - `filter(errorHandler())`). So when the call is returned from secon service, that status is printed as 201 which is expcted. But from the controller in gateway, the response is not getting returned. Instead the response is 401 with the response having custom fields I have set in `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Once the call is returned from second service, why the AuthenticationEntryPoint is getting executed instead of returning the service? How to get the proper response and send back? And if error response is coming from second service, how to handle it in @RestControllerAdvice? or do we need to handle through WebClient filter only? If so how?

**Log from Error handler**

```
Client Response => checkpoint("Body from POST http://localhost:8081/api/v1/course [DefaultClientResponse]")
Status Code = 201 CREATED
```

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:147) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:173) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:280) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:134) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:691) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:612) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:582) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$AsyncRunnable.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:588) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:354) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

---

Comment: `Authentication is done in first service properly.` this is fine  `And when I try to access a URL which connects to second service` is this done through the other service, or just manually from postman to the second service? super unclear. `from the First Service, it always responds with Unauthorized.` so this mean it must go to the first service and then is proxied to the second service. so where is that code? thats the relevant code, why havnt you posted that bit?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have added customer client and controller where it is using.

Comment: Second service I tried through postman and it worked fine. From first service, call is reaching second service and it works fine as an entry is saved in DB and responding with 201. I have added the client code now in update

Comment: You aren't passing any authentication header, so how should the second service know who you are? Authentication information isn't passed automatically, you will need to pass the token yourself in the request being made with the `WebClient`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Authentication is not required in my second service for now. Thats a different case. For now I'm trying to run it without the security. And through postman it worked without any authentication.  And from the logs of first service, the webclient call returned 201. Issue is with first service as I interpret.

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** as well as your `CustomerClient` code.

Comment: I have added the exception stacktrace and also added CustomerClient interface

Comment: could you please remove `.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)` I dont really understand your purpose of setting this? please explain why you have this defined, because your implementation of it doesn't really makes sense

Comment: second, a lot is missing from your question you are saying `Authentication is done in first service properly` but you have not shown us what your request looks like, and where is the code for this endpoint this request is done to? where is this code?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I thought more code was not necessary. This is bearer token authentication. I was referring to this link - https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication. Obviously changed to Spring Boot 3 and also added few more security apis. 
`AuthenticationEntry` point is added to return 401 with custom response data while `AccessDeneiedHandler` is added to return 403 with custom response data as for few apis I'm checking the role as well. If I remove this, for 401 also it is returning with 403 which I certainly don't want.

Comment: you are saying that the call to the first service is failing, because you are getting a 401 UNAUTHORIZED back. Then its suitable that you post THAT code that handles that request, and you post what your request looks like. Also posting a link to a blog post doesn't help anyone. We are trying to help you and YOUR code, not some code in a blog post. That blogpost is also following bad practices as it is implementing a custom filter for handling JWTs. Spring has had built in hadling of JWTs built into the framework since 2017. So the person that wrote that blogpost apparently doesnt read docs.

Comment: HTTP standards declare that certain status codes are to bo returned during specific events. Thats why there are standards and you should not change these standards if you want your service to be interoperable with other services and libraries. 401s are returned, when you are encouraging the client to authenticate themselfes, while 403 is when the client is doing something not allowed. By returning 401 hen there should be a 401 you will confuse client, encouraging them to authenticate themselfes, when they are actually doing something forbidden. Which is semantically incorrect.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm sorry if my question was not clear. I have updated it with more cdetails and error flow.

Comment: I added those handler to return the same http status only, but with custom fields in response if you see. If authentication fails, I'm returning 401 and if user is not allowed for some operation it is returning 403. But in those cases I'm returning some custom fields also. Thats why I have added those handlers in Web Security

Comment: Call reaches the controller in first service after authentication and authorization. And the controller is calling the second service to create a customer entry in DB. Then the second service returns with 201. Reaches the call back in first service. And instead of returning the same response I received from second service as per the controller, it is returning 401.

Comment: well your logs state different, and its impossible to know the cause unless you post your FULL debug logs of the first service

Comment: That's what even I don't understand why Authentication Entry point is getting executed after the controller is executed. That all the logs I have as well.

Comment: And If I use mono.block() based on the suggested answer I'm getting the response properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue. I was using WebFlux for using WebClient only and not the complete reactive feature.
I did not add the *`WebClient`* filter method. Error responses were handled by `@RestControllerAdvice`.

Change your controller to return the body instead of Mono/Flux

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Customer> create(@RequestBody @Valid CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
    log.info("Creating....");
    return customerClient.create(customerDTO).block();
}
```

And for handling errors, the WebClient throws *WebClientResponseException* and you can handle it in @RestControllerAdvice something like below.

```
@ExceptionHandler(WebClientResponseException.class)
public ProblemDetail handleWebClientException(WebClientResponseException e) {
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = e.getStatusCode();
    var responseBody = e.getResponseBodyAs(<ExpctedResponseClass>.class);
    String message = "Details based on response";
    return ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(statusCode, message);
}
```

Comment: This won't solve a thing, nor should you use blocking here.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please explain why it won't solve?

Comment: Spring MVC can handle the Mono and will automatically subscribe on it and delegate to the async servlet handling. Adding a `block` in there to make it syncronous won't help.

Comment: This is working for me. @M.Deinum, what is the best solution though?